# get element by classname for IE11

Tags: getelementsbyclassname, selectors-api

I've an issue with queryselectorall and IE11.
It works on IE10 and firefox but with last cheet
Do you have a solution for having an element by his classname?

```
if(document.querySelectorAll(".classname"))
{
    alert('ici');
    document.querySelectorAll(".classname").style.display = "none";
}
```

The alert and display none is working on everything except Internet Explorer 11

thanks

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector IE 11 is supported

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/thoughts-on-queryselectorall/

Comment: thanks for your links, which alternate do you use for making works this in IE11?

Comment: no need for alternative as IE11 supports it.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/r3XCd/12/

```
if (typeof document.querySelectorAll !== undefined) {
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".classname").length > 0) {
      var element = document.querySelectorAll(".classname");
      element[0].style.display="none";
    }
}
```

For multiple elements:
http://jsfiddle.net/r3XCd/19/

```
if (typeof document.querySelectorAll !== undefined) {
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".classname").length > 0) {
      var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".classname");
      for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor ='red';
       }
    }
}
```